# Generic Collection inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, generics, framework-design

I'mm building a WPF app with MVVM and am using ObservableCollection.  While working on my ViewModel, I decided to inspect the type definition of the ObservableCollection and I saw something that I thought was odd:

```
// class definition for ObservableCollection
ObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
// derives from Collection<T>
... 
// class definition for Collection<T>
Collection<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T> ... (as well as non-generics)
```

Now, here's the question:

```
If ICollection<T> implements IEnumerable<T> 
AND 
IList<T> implements ICollection<T> AS WELL AS IEnumerable<T>
...
...
Why does Collection<T> implement ALL THREE?
```

Is this really how its implemented or is this VS2010 playing tricks on me?

Comment: My interpretation is that it implements the interface directly.

Comment: @Blam - Can you clarify your comment? Using "it" and "the interface" is not constructive when the question discusses multiple classes and interfaces

Comment: If it is not constructive then just ignore it.  It would be the subject of the question.  Interface would be interface.  Implement directly would be implement directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a class, say `Collection<T>` implements `IList<T>`, and you would go to the definition in Visual Studio, it will show you all interfaces that `Collection<T>` implements. If `Collection<T>` implements `IList<T>`, it will also implement `ICollection<T>` and IEnumerable because

```
IList<T> : ICollection<T>
```

and

```
ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
```

etc.

In otherwords, if I write

```
interface IFoo : IBar, IBaz {}
interface IBar {}
interface IBaz {}

class Foobar : IFoo {}
```

Then Visual Studio will give me:

```
Foobar : IFoo, IBar, IBaz {...} (from metadata).
```

If I implement `IFoo`, I must also implement `IBar` because `IFoo` extends `IBar`, thus it makes sense to show that `Foobar` also implement `IBar` and `IBaz` (otherwise I'd only see `IFoo`, and would have to navigate to `IFoo` to see `IBar` etc.)

Comment: Good example. In short, the relationship *implements* is transitive.

Comment: Good answer. I would add that explicitly specifying the base interfaces makes no difference to the compiler - once you've specified that something is an `IList<T>` (and therefore an `ICollection<T>`) specifying `ICollection<T>` *again* is valid although redundant. Also, [Eric Lippert has a post on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/04/so-many-interfaces.aspx).

Comment: Sure, this is what I thought (+1).  I found another scenario that somewhat contrasts with this explanation. System.Data.DataSet implements MarshalByValueComponent with itself implements IDisposable..  ... but I don't see the IDisposable in the DataSet class definition. What gives?

Comment: I'd guess it's simply a design decision made when implementing "Go To Definition", along with the distinction between displaying a base class vs showing implemented interfaces - for interfaces implemented *by the class being viewed*, it was deemed useful to show the entire interface list. Interfaces implemented by its *base* class are perhaps less directly relevant in most cases (though it's always good to know when something is disposable). Whether explicitly shown or not, `DataSet` of course implements `IDisposable` through its base class.

Comment: It'd be nice if the tooling evolved to show the ACTUAL definition of types where that information is made public.  Thanks for the input.  I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Actually not only Visual Studio, but other tools (like Reflector) also will show all interfaces, which are implemented by type. I think this functionality is implemented via [Type.GetInterfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces.aspx):

```
Type type = typeof(MyClass);
Type[] interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
```

This method gets **all** the interfaces **implemented or inherited** by the current Type. *Implemented interfaces* are those, which are declared as a part of definition of the Type:

```
public class MyClass : IList<T>
```

But interfaces can inherit other interfaces. So interfaces, which are inherited by implemented interfaces, are *inherited interfaces*:

```
 public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>

 public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>

 public interface IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable
```

So, here we have three inherited interfaces and one implemented. All are considered as type interfaces.